# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in insert command

Tags: oracle, sqlfiddle

The are many questions with this same title but I can't find an answer among those.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE J
    (A integer)
;

INSERT INTO J (A)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6),
    (7),
    (8),
    (9),
    (10)
;
```

The `create` alone works. The problem is just the insert. I tried in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it several ways  (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48053)):

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO J (A) VALUES (1)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (2)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (3)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (4)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (5)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (6)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (7)
    INTO J (A) VALUES (8)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Or (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f315a)):

```
INSERT INTO J (A)
select  (1) from dual union all
select  (2) from dual union all
select  (3) from dual union all
select  (4) from dual union all
select  (5) from dual union all
select  (6) from dual union all
select  (7) from dual union all
select  (8) from dual union all
select  (9) from dual union all
select  (10) from dual
```

Or even separate `INSERT` statements for each one:

```
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding multiple values into a 1 column table.

You need 
`Insert into J (A)
values (1);`

`Insert into J (A)
values (2);`

etc

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (4);
...
INSERT INTO J (A) VALUES (10);
```